# windows vs Qt transplant to Mac Qt it can't find 'shared_ptr'. When i add 'CONFIG += c++11' it can't find 'u16string' in qstring.h

Tags: c++, windows, macos, qt, visual-studio-2013

When I transplant a Windows Qt vS project to Mac Qt,the Mac Qt Creator can't find `shared_ptr` such as the image of left.

[image]

When I add `CONFIG += c++11` and so on,the Qt creator can't find `u16string` in the `qstring.h` like the image of right.

Comment: Do you need C++11 in your project or not?

Comment: Try: _QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libc++_ in the .pro file (run qmake after you modify the .pro file)